# update multiple object with $gt operator inside array in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to update an array inside document in which i want to perform update operation based on a greater than condition.

Here is my document:

```
{  
  _id:some_id,
  name:"test",
  data:[
         { __id:1,
           __data:[{a:"something"}]
          },
           { __id:2,
           __data:[{a:"something"}]
          },
           { __id:3,
           __data:[{a:"something"}]
          }....
        ]
}
```

I want to subtract 1 from __id of every element in the data array if its __id is greater than 2

Currently i am doing this but it is not working

```
db.collection('collection_name').update({name:"test","data.__id":{$gt:2}},{$inc:{"data.__id":-1}},{multi:true})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [**`$ positional`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)  operator to update value inside an array

```
db.getCollection('test').update(
 { "name": "test" , "data.__id": { "$gt": 2 }},
 { "$inc": { "data.$.__id": -1 }},
 { "multi": true }
)
```

Comment: above query only update single document not all documents matching the condition

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: i tried that before but it wasn't working, and i am also using a callback with this so is that a problem

Comment: No callback or .then is necessary here. `multi:true` didn't work?

Comment: yes take a look at this : collection.update({"name":data.toRoom,"tab_data.__id":{"$gt":parseInt(data.removeWithId)}},{"$inc":{"tab_data.$.__id":-1}},{"multi": true},callback)